# How to build exe file (Desktop App) using ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I am developing ionic project I am trying to generate exe file using IONIC3.
Is where any way to develop exe for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova cant generate .exe files.
You might want to look into electron if you really need an .exe.

if you have trouble viewing your app look [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/starting) this is the ionic documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova, you could try using the cordova-windows platform which has existed for over 5 years.

Also, Electron support is available since Cordova 9.